# How i can to relate 2 Django ChoiceFileds

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, choicefield

I have a problem in my project.
I want to create a ChoiceField to be  categories and subcategories in the models.py file. Well, it must be that I chose the first choice and the second according to the index of the place. For example, like the car and its models, according to the brand I chose in the First ChoiceField, you look at its models in the second field. İn Django.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've done this in the past by creating my own widget, a `CategorizedSelect`, with some jQuery. Here's the code and comments:

`my_app/widgets.py`:
    from django.forms.widgets import Select

```
class CategorizedSelect(Select):
    """
    This widget takes a dict of categories and a list of dicts for items.
    It renders two drop downs, the first of the categories, which then
    populates the second drop down with the items in that category via
    the jQuery chained library.

    For example:

    # Prepare data for chained dropdown field for security
    intl_stocks = Security.objects.filter(
        active=True,
        security_type__short_name="INT",
    ).select_related(
        'exchange',
    ).order_by(
        'exchange__name', 'name',
    )

    exchanges, securities = OrderedDict(), []

    for intl_stock in intl_stocks:
        exchanges[intl_stock.exchange.id] = intl_stock.exchange.name
        securities += [{'category_id': intl_stock.exchange.id, 'id': intl_stock.id, 'name': intl_stock.name}]

    security = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Security.objects.none(),
        widget=CategorizedSelect(
            categories=exchanges,
            items=securities,
        ),
    )
    """
    template_name = 'my_app/widgets/categorized_select.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, categories=None, items=None):
        super().__init__(attrs)
        self.categories = categories
        self.items = items

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['categories'] = self.categories
        context['items'] = self.items

        return context
```

`my_app/templates/my_app/widgets/categorized_select.html`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-chained/1.0.1/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<select id="chain_select_{{ widget.name }}_id" name="chain_select_{{ widget.name }}" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--</option>
    {% for id, name in categories.items %}
        <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br>
<select name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
    <option value="">--</option>
    {% for item in items %}
        {% comment %}
        If we match the initial value set by the Django form, we need to
        set SELECTED on the child, and use jQuery to force the category parent
        drop down to the proper selection as well. We will force item.id to a 
        string since the widget.value.0 is always a string.
        {% endcomment %}
        {% if item.id|stringformat:"i" == widget.value.0 %}
            <option value="{{ item.id }}" class="{{ item.category_id }}" SELECTED>{{ item.name }}</option>
            <script>
                var selected_category_id = {{ item.category_id }}
            </script>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ item.id }}" class="{{ item.category_id }}">{{ item.name }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<script>
$("#{{ widget.attrs.id }}").chained("#chain_select_{{ widget.name }}_id");

if(selected_category_id) {
    $('#chain_select_{{ widget.name }}_id').val(selected_category_id).change();
    $('#chain_select_{{ widget.name }}_id').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#{{ widget.attrs.id }}').prop("disabled", true);
}
</script>
```

The example in the comment shows how this was done for a set of international stocks; the international exchanges were the categories, with the stocks themselves being the items. Good luck!